# Como puedo poner el TextField en una sola fila y los numeros abajo

Tags: java

estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora para una tarea, y no sé como puedo poner la caja del Textfield donde voy a ingresar los numero en fila completa, y abajo de ella los números y las operaciones, no se bien como se una lo de los paneles, por favor alguien me explica, gracias.

```
public class AppletCalculadora extends Applet implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        TextField caja;
        Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b0,bmas,bmenos,bmult,bdiv,bmod,bigual,bborrar,bpunto,bce;
        Panel p1,p2;

    public AppletCalculadora() {

            p1 = new Panel();
            caja = new TextField();
            p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p2 = new Panel();
            p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,3,8,8));
            b1 = new Button("1");
            b2 = new Button("2");
            b3 = new Button("3");
            b4 = new Button("4");
            b5 = new Button("5");
            b6 = new Button("6");
            b7 = new Button("7");
            b8 = new Button("8");
            b9 = new Button("9");
            b0 = new Button("0");
            bmas = new Button("+");
            bmenos = new Button("-");
            bmult = new Button("*");
            bdiv = new Button("/");
            bmod = new Button("%");
            bigual = new Button("=");
            bborrar = new Button("C");
            bpunto = new Button(".");
            bce = new Button("CE");

p1.add(caja);
p2.add(b1);p2.add(b2);p2.add(b3);p2.add(b4);p2.add(b5);
p2.add(b6);p2.add(b7);p2.add(b8);p2.add(b9);p2.add(b0);
p2.add(bmas);p2.add(bmenos);p2.add(bmult);p2.add(bdiv);p2.add(bmod);
p2.add(bigual);p2.add(bborrar);p2.add(bpunto);p2.add(bce);

add(caja); add(b1); add(b2);add(b3);add(b4);add(b5);add(b6);add(b7);add(b8);add(b9);add(b0);add(bmas);add(bmenos);add(bmult);add(bdiv);add(bmod);add(bigual);add(bborrar);add(bpunto);add(bce);add(p1); add(p2);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, si usaras unos JPanel para meter los componentes solo debes añadir estos panel al JFrame no es necesario añadir luego todos los componentes también,debes asignar un Layout a tú Jframe, en este casa un BorderLayout, luego usar los métodos para acomodar el panel1 en el comienzo(NORTH) y el panel2 en el centro(CENTER), aun se podría mejorar pero es lo básico.

```
public void iniciar() {
       //Le ponemos tamaño, titulo y el borderlayout al jframe
        setTitle("Calculadora");
        setSize(600, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

  public calculadora() {

        //Las correciones que indique arriba de ubicar los panel en el norte y centro. 
        //ademas llamamos al metodo iniciar.
        p1 = new JPanel();
        caja = new JTextField();
        caja.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 10,  60));
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 3, 8, 8));
        b1 = new JButton("1");
        b2 = new JButton("2");
        b3 = new JButton("3");
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        b6 = new JButton("6");
        b7 = new JButton("7");
        b8 = new JButton("8");
        b9 = new JButton("9");
        b0 = new JButton("0");
        bmas = new JButton("+");
        bmenos = new JButton("-");
        bmult = new JButton("*");
        bdiv = new JButton("/");
        bmod = new JButton("%");
        bigual = new JButton("=");
        bborrar = new JButton("C");
        bpunto = new JButton(".");
        bce = new JButton("CE");

        p1.add(caja, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p2.add(b1);
        p2.add(b2);
        p2.add(b3);
        p2.add(b4);
        p2.add(b5);
        p2.add(b6);
        p2.add(b7);
        p2.add(b8);
        p2.add(b9);
        p2.add(b0);
        p2.add(bmas);
        p2.add(bmenos);
        p2.add(bmult);
        p2.add(bdiv);
        p2.add(bmod);
        p2.add(bigual);
        p2.add(bborrar);
        p2.add(bpunto);
        p2.add(bce);

        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        iniciar();

    }
```